# Different output in chrome console and rails log

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to add data through cross platform form in rails. Data are also being added but the response in my browser is always an error with some json object.

Output in rails log:-

```
Started POST "/batches.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-01-14 19:33:34 +0545
Processing by BatchesController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"batch"=>{"name"=>"shitalluitel", "course_id"=>"9", "start_date"=>"2016-12-12", "end_date"=>"2016-12-14", "batch_status"=>"1"}}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "current_sign_in_at" = $1, "last_sign_in_at" = $2, "sign_in_count" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "users"."id" = $5  [["current_sign_in_at", 2017-01-14 13:48:34 UTC], ["last_sign_in_at", 2017-01-14 13:47:54 UTC], ["sign_in_count", 77], ["updated_at", 2017-01-14 13:48:34 UTC], ["id", 1]]
   (15.6ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Course Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "courses".* FROM "courses" WHERE "courses"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "batches" ("name", "course_id", "start_date", "end_date", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "shitalluitel"], ["course_id", 9], ["start_date", Mon, 12 Dec 2016], ["end_date", Wed, 14 Dec 2016], ["created_at", 2017-01-14 13:48:34 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-01-14 13:48:34 UTC]]
   (8.7ms)  COMMIT
Entered to true part
Completed 200 OK in 104ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 36.8ms)
```

but in browser it shows as below: -

```
Object {readyState: 0, responseJSON: undefined, status: 0, statusText: "error"}
test.html?_ijt=m511tgfk5o03pohpjpk2ebuppf:88 
Navigated to http://localhost:63342/zeftware/shitalluitel.github.io/test.html?batch%5Bstatus%5D=0
```

Code for submitting form is:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submit-button').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:3000/batches.json",
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
                dataType: "json",
                data: {     
                    batch: {
                      name: $("#name").val(),
                      course_id: $("#course_id").val(),
                      start_date: $("#start_date").val(),
                      end_date: $("#end_date").val(),
                      batch_status: $("#batch_status").val(),
                      }
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                },
              success: function(data) {
                         console.log(data);
                         return false;
                      },
            })
        });
    })
```

Code of my controller is:-

```
class BatchesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  def new
    @batch = Batch.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json
      format.html
    end
  end

  def create
    @batch = Batch.new(batch_param)
    respond_to do |format|
       if @batch.save
         puts "Entered to true part #{@batch.name}"
         format.html { redirect_to @batch, notice: "Save process completed!" }
         format.json { render json: @batch}
       else
         puts "entered to false part"
          format.html {
            flash.now[:notice]="Save proccess coudn't be completed!"
            render :new_batch
          }
          format.json { render json: @batch.errors}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: u should write down your code for submitting the form

Comment: Are you returning any **json response** from your controller action?

Comment: yeah i am returning both html and json response